# Spring Boot with Freemarker - form tags

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, freemarker

I would like to use spring Boot MVC with Freemarker and display a form in a similar way to how it is done with JSP tags. E.g. this form:

```
<form:form method="post" action="save" modelAttribute="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <form:hidden path="id"/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <form:input id="name" path="name" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

Naturally, the tags form:form, form:input, form:hidden etc. are not supported. Is there a way to bind the model to the view in Freemarker?

Comment: Have you read [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-velocity)?

Comment: Condescending comments are not appreciated....thanx

Comment: How to do that is explained in the reference guide in the section I refer to. You might want to read the official documentation before asking a question.

Comment: A simple answer: "You can find it at...." is much nicer to read. Naturally, I have read the docs and did not find it. Otherwise, I wouldn't have posted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-simple-binding

```
<!-- freemarker macros have to be imported into a namespace. We strongly
recommend sticking to spring -->
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring />
<html>
    ...
    <form action="" method="POST">
        Name:
        <@spring.bind "command.name" />
        <input type="text"
            name="${spring.status.expression}"
            value="${spring.status.value?default("")}" /><br>
        <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error> <b>${error}</b> <br> </#list>
        <br>
        ...
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
    ...
</html>
```